# hashmap input in jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

can someone tell me how to set a hashmap value in jsp?

The object is

car with:

```
private Map<String, Float> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();
```

in the jsp i want do soemthing like this

```
<input type='hidden' name='myobject.myHashmap["setvalue string"]' value='my value for string' />
<input type='hidden' name='myobject.myHashmap["setvalue float"]' value='my value for float' />
```

Answer (score 2):

It is doable, using a combination of beans and jsp tags, but beware - you are doing it wrong and what you want is wrong (and probably not what you need). My solution works well, but I think you should throw it away and change your app anyway (unless it's impossible or there is a great pressure of time).

1. If you are using plain jsp (as opposed to JSF) then HTML is just a template; JSP does not know the difference between "<input name='x'>' and 'pancakes'. Forms in JSP can't do anything real (like execute actions or push values to beans). You have to create a vanilla html form, catch its params (using implicit variable 'param') and act.
2. Such "catching and acting" does not really belong in JSP. It should be done somewhere else.
3. In pure JSP there is a possibility of moving data between java beans and between java beans and different request properties (like parameters or cookies), using jsp:setProperty. There is a catch: properties to be written can't be dynamic.
4. Therefore, to achieve your goal, you MUST write a bit of Java, that takes some static properties (data and the target map) and uses it; what's more, the usage must happen inside a setter. It cannot be really universal, because at runtime we do not know the types of keys and values in the map (due to erasure).
5. Handle with care:

`// MapAppender`

```
package a.b.c;

import java.util.Map;

public class MapAppender {
    private String key;
    private Float value;

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setValue(Float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setMap(Map map) {
        if (key != null && value != null) map.put(key, value);
    }

}

// How to use it on page:

<jsp:useBean id="object"  scope="session" class="a.b.c.ObjectWithMap" />

<jsp:useBean id="appender"  scope="request" class="a.b.c.MapAppender" />
<jsp:setProperty name='appender' property='key' value='${param.string}' />
<jsp:setProperty name='appender' property='value' value='${param.float}' />
<jsp:setProperty name='appender' property='map' value='${object.map}' />

<form>
    <input name='string' value='test' />
    <input name='float' value='3.25' />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```